# HQL: combine "insert into ... select" with fixed parameters values

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have HQL statement:

```
insert into Item (ost, value, comments, startTime, endTime, proposedBy) 
select si.ost, si.value, si.comments, si.endTime, si.endTime, u 
from Item si, User u 
where si.ost = ? and u.id = ?
```

How could it be modified to use parameters' values for `ost` and `startTime` columns while taking other columns from `select`?

Answer (score 0):

Can’t be done in HQL; it doesn’t allow parameter references in the select clause.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that last answer. I am using NH 3.2 and I was able to get this to work

```
var hql = @"INSERT INTO EventFacility (Facility, Event, Owner, Position) 
SELECT f, :evt, :own, :position from Facility f where f.Id IN (105, 109, 110)";

var @event = Session.Get<Event>(351931);
var query = Session.CreateQuery(hql)
                .SetInt32("position", 0)
                .SetEntity("evt", @event)
                .SetEntity("own", @event.Owner);

var x = query.ExecuteUpdate();
Assert.AreEqual(3, x);
```

In this example I needed to create a new EventFacility object. With pretty much all the fields you see here. The Event entity has another entity, Owner hanging off of it.

Answer (score 0):

We can do so by using [setParameter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method and refer to [example 6 of HQL and JPQL User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/query/hql/HQL.html).
In addition, "?" should be replaced by Named Parameter due to [Legacy-style query parameters (`?`) are no longer supported](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Hibernate_5.3_Migration_Guide#Positional_Parameters_are_not_Supported) after Hibernate 5.3. (For better readability and maintainability, Named Parameter should be used even if you are using earlier version)

Following method demonstrates above changes:

```java
public void insertIntoSelectWithParameter(String ost, LocalDateTime startTime, String fromOst, Integer fromUserId) {
    String hql = "insert into Item (ost, value, comments, startTime, endTime, proposedBy) "
            + "select :ost, si.value, si.comments, :startTime, si.endTime, u " 
            + "from Item si, User u "
            + "where si.ost = :fromOst and u.id = :fromUserId";
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Query<?> query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("ost", ost);
    query.setParameter("startTime", startTime);
    query.setParameter("fromOst", fromOst);
    query.setParameter("fromUserId", fromUserId);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```