# copy data from one table to another table using HQL, not working

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

i have two tables newstudent and oldstudent, both table have id, name, email columns. in oldstudent table some datas are present. i want to copy those data to newstudent table using **HQL**. i have mapped both tables in **hibernate.cfg.xml** file. All hibernate configuration is working fine but my problem is in HQL `INSERT INTO NewStudent(id, name, email) SELECT o.id, o.name, o.email FROM OldStudent o`. it is showing error

**Main**

```
package insert.hql;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class InsertTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "INSERT INTO NewStudent(id, name, email) SELECT o.id, o.name, o.email FROM OldStudent o";
        Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
        int i = q.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();

        s.close();
        sf.close();
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="oldstudent.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="newstudent.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: line 1:70: unexpected token: FROM
Nov 30, 2016 1:35:35 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:70: unexpected token: FROM
line 1:70: unexpected token: FROM
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:996)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3609)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3387)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3259)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2964)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2730)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2591)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2555)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2471)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2436)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2146)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2389)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1422)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1325)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1062)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.insertStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at insert.hql.InsertTest.main(InsertTest.java:20)

Nov 30, 2016 1:35:35 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:97: unexpected token: o
Nov 30, 2016 1:35:35 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:97: unexpected token: o
line 1:97: unexpected token: o
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2416)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1422)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1325)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1062)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.insertStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at insert.hql.InsertTest.main(InsertTest.java:20)

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FROM near line 1, column 70 [INSERT INTO NewStudent(id, name, email) SELECT o.id, o.name, o.email FROM insert.hql.OldStudent o]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at insert.hql.InsertTest.main(InsertTest.java:20)
```

Comment: take a look at this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820119/hql-combine-insert-into-select-with-fixed-parameters-values

Comment: and this URL may helps you in HQL: http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/complete-hibernate-query-language-hql-tutorial/

Comment: above two links are tried, but not working

Comment: Do you try use a native SQL

Comment: no i didn't try, i want to know why in my case `INSERT INTO NewStudent(id, name, email) SELECT o.id, o.name, o.email FROM OldStudent o` not working

Comment: We try with native SQL to know if the problem is not from SQL query